# Identify a user among multiple application instances in Spotify Apps API 1.x

Tags: spotify

I would like to implement a "Like" feature where a user can like tracks that will be stored in the backend. When loading the application all starred tracks should be retrieved from the backend. For that I would need a unique identifier for the user so that it can be identified among multiple Spotify applications so where ever he logs in the presented information will be the same.

I am aware that there is a high focus of user privacy in Spotify. However in Spotify Apps API < 1.0 it was at least possible to call `models.session.getAnonymousUserId` in order to get a unique identifer. I am missing this feature in Apps API 1.x. The only user attribute where I seem to have permission is `models.session.user.uri`, which returns `spotify:user:@` constantly and is therefore not unique.

Are there still any possibilities to identify users among multiple applications in Spotify Apps API 1.x?

Answer (score 1):

The [`models.session.user.identifier`](https://developer.spotify.com/docs/apps/api/1.0/api-models-user.html) property in the 1.X API is the same as the 0.X `models.session.getAnonymousUserId`. There is (intentionally) no way to track users over multiple applications using the Spotify API.

Comment: ```models.session.user.get('identifier')``` returns a promise that has ```_need``` set to ```4```. I guess that this is why ```models.session.user.identifier``` stays ```undefined```. I cannot find any documentation on this Promise attribute, but it sounds to me like I am missing some permission here. Do you know more about it and how I can access this attribute?

Comment: The `models.session.user` object is always blank. Its uri is always `spotify:user:@`. When attempting to load the 'identifier' property via `models.session.user.load('identifier')`, it fails with the message: **invalid-uri:' is not a user URI.'** Does anyone know how to get around this, or is this a bug in the 1.x apps api?